# How to rescue USB drives?

Tags: usb, centos, centos-7, dd, fdisk

A `dd` command on CentOS 7 failed, and now my USB disk (`/dev/sdf`) cannot be written to.

These are the outputs I get:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdf
lsblk: /dev/sdf: not a block device

$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE   MOUNTPOINT
sda             8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk   
├─sda1          8:1    0   200M  0 part   /boot/efi
├─sda2          8:2    0     1G  0 part   /boot
└─sda3          8:3    0 231.7G  0 part   
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm    /
  ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm    [SWAP]
  └─rhel-home 253:2    0   166G  0 lvm    /home
sdb             8:16   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─sdb1          8:17   0   2.7T  0 part   
  └─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid10 /local/raid0
sdc             8:32   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─sdc1          8:33   0   2.7T  0 part   
  └─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid10 /local/raid0
sdd             8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─sdd1          8:49   0   2.7T  0 part   
  └─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid10 /local/raid0
sde             8:64   0   2.7T  0 disk   
└─sde1          8:65   0   2.7T  0 part   
  └─md0         9:0    0   5.5T  0 raid10 /local/raid0
sdf             8:80   1   7.5G  0 disk   
└─sdf1          8:81   1   7.5G  0 part  

$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero  of=/dev/sdf
dd: writing to ‘/dev/sdf’: No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000159246 s, 0.0 kB/s

$ hdparm -Tt /dev/sdf1

/dev/sdf1:
mlock() failed on timing buf: Cannot allocate memory
 BLKGETSIZE failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mlock() failed on timing buf: Cannot allocate memory
BLKFLSBUF failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
$ hdparm -Tt /dev/sdf

/dev/sdf:
mlock() failed on timing buf: Cannot allocate memory
 BLKGETSIZE failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
mlock() failed on timing buf: Cannot allocate memory
BLKFLSBUF failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device

$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdf bs=512 count=1
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdf’: No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000144288 s, 0.0 kB/s

$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdf
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdf: Inappropriate ioctl for device

$ sudo mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/usbstick/
mount: /dev/sdf1 is not a block device (maybe try `-o loop'?)
$ sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/usbstick/
mount: /dev/sdf is not a block device (maybe try `-o loop'?)
```

Is there any way to recover the USB stick (I have several in the same status).

Comment: Don't know if you have seen this page or not  https://askubuntu.com/questions/101637/usb-turn-write-protection-off
__To turn off disk device`s write protect, we use the low level system utility hdparm like this:__
__sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb__      (in your case it may be __sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sdf1__)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that somewhere along the way, a **regular file** (not a special block device) was created for `/dev/sdf`.
Once the USB stick was ejected, and that regular file deleted, upon inserting the USB stick - all is fine.